# exec with ';' in python

Tags: python, printing, exec

I am creating a string, to print the fields in a list, . the fields should be separated by ';', code snippet looks like this( simplified code, not actual )

```
list = ["abc","xyz","pqr"]
str = "print " +  "list[0]"  + ";" + "list[2]" # This is dynamically generated
exec (str)
```

My problem here is, with exec statement, it prints only "xyz" , because of the semi colon. what is the best way to solve this, so that the exec statement prints "xyz;pqr"

Comment: This seems like a really unnecessary use of exec ... Are you sure you need it rather than string formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are generating the following code:

```
print list[0];list[2]
```

Note that the `;` is **not quoted**. Since a `;` is used by Python to separate multiple simple statements on a line, Python executes the `print list[0]` first, then `list[2]` (which ends up doing nothing).

You'd have to generate this code instead:

```
print list[0] + ';' + list[2]
```

which you could do with:

```
str = "print " +  "list[0]"  + " + ';' + " + "list[2]"
```

However, you should not be using code generation *at all*. Use standard Python methods to join or format a string. You could use `str.format()`:

```
print '{};{}'.format(list[0], list[2])
```

or you could use `str.join()`:

```
print ';'.join([list[0], list[2]])
```

If you must vary what code is executed based on some other variables, try to avoid `exec` still. You could use `from __future__ import print_function` or encapsulate the `print` statement in a new function, then call functions dynamically. You can always use a [dispatch table](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182093/why-store-a-function-inside-a-python-dictionary/182095#182095) to map a string to a function to call, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = "print" + "list[0]" + "';'" + "list[2]"
```

or

```
str = "print" + "list[0]" + "/;" + "list[2]"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Python optionally allows semicolons to delimit two separate statements ([Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html)). So when you use `exec` on the evaluated statement `print "abc";"xyz"`, Python thinks they are two separate statements, hence, only `print`ing `"abc"`.

You could use single quotes around the semicolon to show that it is a string and concatenate them with their surrounding strings:

```
# Refrain from using list and str as they are built-ins
l = ["abc", "xyz", "pqr"]
s = "print " +  "l[0]"  + "+';'+" + "l[2]"
exec(s)
```